# iOS 6.0 Facebook 3.1 login after first time application install issues with Enhanced Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I spend the hole day on this and search stack overflow but can't find a solution. 
My code been running with no issue with iOS 5.1 and 3.1, on iOS 6.0 I run into issues.

I first remove the app from Facebook app setting to simulate first time user. 
I then install the app and try to login.
Everything works fine as long as I don't login to Facebook from the iOS setting (i.e my app don't use the Enhanced Auth Dialog).
 If I login in teh iOS setting I get errors like :

Error on Facebook login Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1dd7d570 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app must ask for a basic read permission at install time." UserInfo=0x1ddab400 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app must ask for a basic read permission at install time.}}

I have the following code

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_about_me", @"friends_about_me",
                        @"user_birthday", @"friends_birthday",
                        @"user_work_history", @"friends_work_history",
                        @"user_relationships", @"friends_relationships",
                        @"user_notes", @"friends_notes", nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
```

The only solution I found that works is to replace the

openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions

Back to the deprecated:

openActiveSessionWithPermissions

Comment: Have you tried removing permissions one by one to see which ones are the problem? I can't see any that are something other than read permissions. It's not clear from the docs what basic read permissions are.

Comment: I agree with the commenter above, it's something with the permission and you should try adding them one by one too see which causes the problem.

Comment: I did tried that, It worked when I put only birthday permission.

Comment: Thanks, I agree it really not clear what can you ask. I did tried that, It worked when I put only birthday permission. I read in the docs that you must have either birthday/location/email (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/). But it also say there you can ask for additional permissions. Personally I think it is a bug in the integration between FB and iOS and at first you can ask ONLY for one of the three above.